# How to avoid uninstalling previously installed ExePackage (redistributables) while installing a WiX Bundle?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I have a Bundle that installs and uninstalls VC 2012 redist. Its working fine if there was no VC 2012 redist installed previously. if there is a VC 2012 redist already installed, then while uninstalling my bundle, it uninstalls the VC 2012 redist as well.
All I want is that it must not uninstall the VC 2012 redist if it was previously installed. I was trying to use the variable element with persisted attribute set to "yes". But I am not sure how it works. any pointers to this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't want it to be permanent if my bundle is installing it. I want to remove it when I installed it but don't remove it when its already being installed.

Answer (score 4):

Bundles can reference count contained packages. Add a `Provides` element from the `WixDependencyExtension` and the Bundles that use the same `Provides` element will correct reference count.

Unfortunately, VCRedist doesn't document a standard `Provides` key so there is no real way to correctly reference count the package. Thus, the VCRedist team expects you to mark it Permanent.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Is there a way that a variable can store info whether or not the bundle installed the package or not? As of now I did a workaround by creating 2 miss named pre and post and integrated in the bundle before and after vc redist 2012 package. pre writes a registry variable saying weather vc redist was installed or not previously. I use this registry in detectcondition of vc redist package. now because detect condition will uninstall the package while uninstallation.

Comment: now, if pre had detected the vc redist and had made the registry as true, then Post msi will change the registry to a value which will be false for vc redist detect condition on uninstallation. This is how I am doing it right now.

Comment: It is serving my purpose for now, but making vc redist permanent is good option. But I was thinking of other than vc redist packages which needs to be uninstalled and deviced this method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [ExePackage](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html) element to install the redist?

If so, there is a "Permanent" element that you can set to prevent it from being uninstalled when the bundle is removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want it to be permanent if my bundle is installing it. I want to remove it when I installed it but don't remove it when its already being installed. Is it possible by using permanent attribute?

Comment: It looks like the "permanent" attribute only prevents the package from being uninstalled.  It might be possible to use DetectCondition and InstallConditions to not install the package if it's already present. You'd have to test, but I think that the bootstrapper won't uninstall packages it didn't originally install.

Comment: BUT - you can really get yourself into trouble doing this.  Imagine a scenario where your bootstrapper was the first to install the redist. and then the user installs another program that needs the redist as well. If the user uninstalls your program, then it would also remove the redist, which would break the second program.

Comment: Aaron Stebner recommends not removing the redist. package because it might be used by other programs.  This is a really old discussion (2008), but read the comments here for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/02/07/update-regarding-silent-install-of-the-vc-8-0-runtime-vcredist-packages.aspx

Comment: I don't think bootstrapper remembers what it installed installation as per my testing. DetectCondition seems to be mandatory for uninstallation. if its not provided or if it evaluates to false, then redist uninstallation does not happen. If it evaluates to true, then it will uninstall the redist even it was not installed by it.... :(... Keeping the redist permanently is good, but my requirement is not to keep it if it was installed by me.