# Wix ExePackage Side by Side Install without Uninstall

Tags: wix, upgrade, uninstallation

I have two products which I'm trying to write an installer for. Both products are wix bundles which both have a third product bundle as a requirement.

Ideally what I want to happen when you install one is:

- If Product3 is not installed then it should be.
- If Product3 is installed and installed version is higher or the same do nothing.
- If Product3 is installed and installed version is lower then upgrade.
- If uninstalling and product1 or 2 is still installed do not uninstall product3.

So far I was able to conquer some of these points but not all at the same time.

Originally I tried getting the installed version using a ProductSearch and using `InstallCommand`. However I ran into problems with uninstalling when doing side by side installs because the installcommand is more like "requested install state" and so if I don't want it to install when it detects the same version it actually starts uninstalling it.

I took a look at this similar answer:

[How to avoid uninstalling previously installed ExePackage (redistributables) while installing a WiX Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603313/how-to-avoid-uninstalling-previously-installed-exepackage-redistributables-whi)

which suggested using the `provideskey` and `requires` elements but I cannot find any useful documentation on them whatsoever. I tried experimenting with it but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

I've looked at `RelatedBundle` but I'm not sure it's what I'm after. Seems more targeted at hotfixing systems.

I was hoping there was a way of doing this without having to resort to custom actions since that seems a bit extreme for what seems to be rather simple functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I figured out how to get the DependencyExtension working.

In the example below ProductC is a Wix Bundle executable. This bundle includes an MSI file. I use a productSearch to look for the upgrade code of that MSI file (NOT THE BUNDLE) to detect if it's already installed.

In your bundle file for project A and B:

```
<Wix xmlns:dep="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/DependencyExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <Bundle>
        <util:ProductSearch Id="ProductCInstallSearch"
                            UpgradeCode="{ProductC_MSI_UpgradeCode_GUID}"
                            Variable="ProductCInstalled"
                            Result="state"/>
        <dep:Requires Id="ProductCRequired" ProviderKey="ProductC"/>
        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="ProductC_pkg"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
    <Fragment Id="Required_Pkgs">
        <PackageGroup Id="ProductC_Pkg">
            <ExePackage Id="ProductC_Bundle"
                        Permanent="no"
                        DetectCondition="NOT ProductCInstalled = 2"
                        InstallCommand="/quiet"
                        UninstallCommand="/uninstall /quiet">
                <dep:Provides Key="ProductC"
                              Version="0.0.0.0">
                    <dep:RequiresRef Id="ProductCRequired"/>
                </dep:Provides>
            </ExePackage>
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Now you can install A and B in any arrangement and when uninstalling product C will only be removed when the last one is uninstalled.